I want to add sliver list between sliver list for comment and reply section in flutter
I have comment and reply section! for post detail like facebook
there are sliver app , sliverToBoxAdapter and sliver list within the CustomScrollViewWidget,
But I don't want to use the shrinkwrap:tru , fixHeight and column method,
how Can I make it for the flutter
I am trying the Customscrollview and sliverlist . but I was expecting that , the comment and reply section best practice with the flutter framework!

Please share the code that you have tried.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
